# How to boost system sound output?

Tags: windows, audio, amplification

When I use Earphones, I feel that my system output is very low, I have set all the volume output to  maximum in "control panel\Sounds and Audio devices", but still not satisfactory. May be my earphones output proportionality is lower.

No problem with sub-woofer, I think its because of the amplifier.

Is there any software to boost up system volume output to compensate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a good question...  When I was in a band a few years back, I was in the unique position to need to actually "not hear" the band and focus on what was in my ears.  I had noise canceling headphones already but this wasn't enough.  So I bought a 4 channel headphone amplifier.  Now this is probably overkill for your application, but you can get scaled down versions.  I know there are many of these out there.  You just need to do some Google searching for "headphone amp" and see what you get.

If this is too much, look into noise canceling headphones.  Although they don't necessarily boost the sound, they eliminate the outside sound to the extent that it seems louder.

I know this isn't software, but I found this was a good path for me to take with the same problem.

Comment: fine :) I will have a look at it when I go for shopping. :)
thanks for the response.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Most likely this is a hardware limitation. The only solutions is to find or build a mini headphone amplifier (it takes a line in and a line out. line out is an amplified line in). They are relatively easy to build, but it's difficult to find portable ones that are sold.

Edit:
Maybe I was wrong. [http://www.amazon.com/Fiio-E3-Headphone-Amplifier/dp/B001MPWMDA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001MPWMDA) looks promising. only $10 and takes a single AAA battery for 20 hours of life.

Comment: its about 6.25 on dealextreme. http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.14823

Comment: Thanks for the response :),
I will have a look :) Regards,

Comment: "Most likely this is a hardware limitation" sometimes the problem is the source media you are playing has low signal levels, and its insane to expect fully pre-processing all media before playing it just so the volume is satisfactory. 

Also, a "loudness" filter at runtime could be nice on a system-wide scale.